# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener double select issue

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am experiencing a odd problem. My OnItemSelectedListener seems only works one time, i mean that it shows my test Toast at the first time when clicking the coresponding items, but it doesn't show the test Toast when i hit the same item at the second time.( it does work when clicking a different item at the second time) What is the problem? plz help me

partial code is here

```
        //get task object from menu
    taskListArr = new ArrayList<Task>();

    taskListArr = getCurrentTasks(taskListArr);

    myTask=new TaskListAdapter(this, 0, taskListArr);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TaskModel.sorts);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sortSpinner.setAdapter(aa);
    sortSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    if(arg2 == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Collections.sort(taskListArr);
        taskListView.setAdapter(myTask);
    }
    if(arg2 == 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Collections.sort(taskListArr, new DateComparator());
        taskListView.setAdapter(myTask);
    }
    if(arg2 == 2){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Collections.sort(taskListArr, new PriorityComparator());
        taskListView.setAdapter(myTask);
    }
    position = arg2;
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out spinner in android developers site http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

```
A view that displays one child at a time and lets the user pick among them. The items in the Spinner come from the Adapter associated with this view.
```

It selects one child at a time. So Selecting the already selected child again will not invoke onItemSelected function.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, but I still need to figure out how to invoke it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

i agree with user936414 answer he is right but if still you want that your toast come again then add a on touch listener on your spinner and in the ontouch event add this

```
line sortSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

by this each time as you touch your spinner listener will get invoked again and you will get the on itemselected each time

Comment: Thanx, I will try it, but it doesnot seem working. Maybe I need to create a custom adpter to handle this problem.

Comment: Sry, i tried but failed. I used Menu listener to achieve the problem. Thanks